# Slick3: blog function implemented, compiled, but won't store the data in DB

Tags: scala, playframework

the code below compiles but it does not store any blog data created through the web interface. Other than blogService, I have userService and authTokenService and they both works fine, so I assume there’s nothing wrong on postgres side.

I’m new to scala and slick, so I am wondering I may be overlooking very trivial or critical mistakes.

Do you see anything wrong in the code? Or would you tell me what I can do to isolate the problem? (I tried to minimize and simplify the code to isolate the problem, but still can't figure this out.)

BlogForm.scala:

```
object BlogForm {

  val form = Form(
    mapping(
      "title" -> nonEmptyText,
      "content" -> nonEmptyText
    )(Data.apply)(Data.unapply)
  )

  case class Data(
    title: String,
    content: String
  )
}
```

BlogController.scala:

```
class BlogController @Inject() (
  val messagesApi: MessagesApi,
  silhouette: Silhouette[DefaultEnv],
  userService: UserService,
  blogService: BlogService,
  implicit val webJarAssets: WebJarAssets)
  extends Controller with I18nSupport {

  def submit: Action[AnyContent] = silhouette.SecuredAction.async { implicit request =>
    BlogForm.form.bindFromRequest.fold(
      form => Future.successful(BadRequest(views.html.blog.blog(request.identity, form))),
      data => {
        blogService.create(data.title, data.content, request.identity)
        Future.successful(Ok(views.html.index(Some(request.identity))))
      }
    )
  }
}
```

BlogServiceImpl.scala:

```
class BlogServiceImpl @Inject() (blogDAO: BlogDAO, clock: Clock) extends BlogService {

  def create(title: String, content: String, user: User): Future[Int] = {
    blogDAO.save(Blog(
      // id = None,
      title = title,
      content = content,
      userID = user.userID,
      createdAt = clock.now
    ))
  }
}
```

BlogDAOImpl.scala:

```
class BlogDAOImpl @Inject() (protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends BlogDAO {

  val dbConfig: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] = dbConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile]
  val db: JdbcBackend#DatabaseDef = dbConfig.db

  import dbConfig.driver.api._

  def save(blog: Blog): Future[Int] = {
    db.run(
      blogs += DbBlog(blog.title, blog.content, blog.userID.toString, blog.createdAt.toString))
  }
}
object BlogDAOImpl {

  private val blogs = TableQuery[BlogTable]

}
```

BlogTable.scala:

```
case class DbBlog(
  title: String,
  content: String,
  userID: String,
  createdAt: String
)


class BlogTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[DbBlog](tag, "blogs") {

  def title: Rep[String] = column[String]("title")

  def content: Rep[String] = column[String]("content")

  def userID: Rep[String] = column[String]("uesr_id")

  def createdAt: Rep[String] = column[String]("created_at")

  override def * : ProvenShape[DbBlog] = (title, content, userID, createdAt) <> (DbBlog.tupled, DbBlog.unapply)

}
```

I’ll omit the binding file and Blog model here.

Again the code is compiled. What possibly causes this kind of error?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to `map` after `blogService.create`. That future might not finish and you **already/immediately** return an answer with `Future.successful`. So, try this: `blogService.create(...).map{res => Ok(views.html.index(Some(request.identity))) }`.

Comment: Your explanation made total sense, and it cleared the problem right away. Please post it as an answer, then I can accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped, @hirofujitaaki . I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `map` after `blogService.create`. That future might not finish and you already/immediately return an answer with `Future.successful`. So, try this:

```
blogService.create(...).map{ res => 
  Ok(views.html.index(Some(request.identity)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

BlogDAOImpl.scala:

Try this

```
@Singleton
class BlogDAOImpl @Inject() (protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends BlogDAO {
   val dbConfig: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] = dbConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile]
   val db: JdbcBackend#DatabaseDef = dbConfig.db

   import dbConfig.driver.api._

   private val blogs = TableQuery[BlogTable] // this line is here as you can't create object of a @Singleton annotated class

   def save(blog: Blog): Future[Int] = {
     db.run(
       blogs += DbBlog(blog.title, blog.content, blog.userID.toString, blog.createdAt.toString))
   }
}
```

You need to inject the **class BlogDAOImpl** where you use the object of this class.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I didn't try it but since I created `val blogs` in the companion object, the BlogDAOImpl class should be able to access it.

Comment: I'm writing the `val blogs` inside the class because if you use `@Singleton` annotation in a class you can't create a companion object, i.e. the class cannot be instantiated more than once.